# In Azure Devops while creating queries. anybody knows what is the use of 'Query Text' Parameter?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

In Azure Devops while creating queries. anybody knows what is the use of 'Query Text' Parameter?

Not able to figure out what is this used for

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of [accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

It is related to Test Suite:

> Field used to capture the query defined for a Query-based suite type.
>
> Reference name=Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.QueryText, Data type=PlainText

as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/build-test-integration?view=azure-devops#other-fields

Answer (score 1):

@GregL has mentioned the `Query Text` parameter in doc:[Build and test integration queries - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/build-test-integration?view=azure-devops#other-fields). Here is using example to understand the conception well.

1 create query based suit in Test Plans menu.
[image: query based suit]

2 config filters and create suite .(query work items based on field `Work Item Type` match with group `Microsoft.TestCaseCategory`)

[image: config filters]

Note: you can transform to WIQL syntax and it is `Query text`. Refer to doc:[WIQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops#query-language-overview)

```
select 
[System.Id], 
[System.WorkItemType], 
[System.Title], 
[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority],
 [System.AssignedTo], 
[System.AreaPath] 
from WorkItems 
where [System.TeamProject] = @project 
and [System.WorkItemType] in group 'Microsoft.TestCaseCategory'
```

3  query work items base on a filed `Query Text` match with a previous value `[System.Title]` or other word included in query text in step 2. **Path:Board->Queries->New Query**
[image: query]